# Shopify Changing Price Based on Large Number of Variants

Tags: shopify, liquid

So I am trying to take payment and book appointments for my oil change shop, I found an app that takes care of the scheduling, but now I need to make the product change prices based on the make/model/year of the car. Pricing is pretty simple, $49, $59 or $79 based on the labor for the specific make/model/year. I have a database and excel sheet with the corresponding price for every car we service.

I've tried a lot of apps and none of them seem to fit. Currently, I'm using Infinite Product Options which allows me to change the price based model but doesn't pay attention to the year (which I could live with) but I can't find a way to validate the selection. i.e. if Ford is selected as the make, it should only show cards made by Ford in the model dropdown.

Is there a better way to do this? Is this a feature in the app that I am missing?

Appreciate any help you can offer!

Answer (score 0):

A long time ago I made a car shop or two or three. All of them used the standard MODEL/MAKE/YEAR selections for choosing things like available tires, etc.

So that magic is controlled by a mafia and you pay for access to it. It costs something like $2000 but that may have changes. Anyway, if someone chooses Ford, they only get Ford cars, which means MAKE choices are so much easier. I suppose it is also smart enough to know you cannot have a 1972 Ford Taurus.

Once you get past that brain dead selection, you could present the correct variant, and hence the correct price by having that selector match variants based on some magic. A back-end script might use the MAKE/MODEL/YEAR result to find a product that matches the make, then the 100 variants would cover model (for the most part).

Anyway, tough for you as yes, those low-fruit on the tree Apps for product options are generally too simple for serious use.